# How to center an ImageView with two TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout

How is the xml to do something like this ?.

### [image: Sample]

I.e. I have two TextView, one below the other, both aligned to the left. Also, on the same "line" I've an ImageView aligned to the right. Lastly i need to center vertically the image with the TextViews.

Comment: Use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

Comment: @minipif is right on the money. You should use a `RelativeLayout`. Learn it from the android engineer, Romain Guy himself - http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take RelativeLayout as the parent,Take two in  textviews at left of the parent ,below one another. And place ImageView at parent right, vertically center

Check this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:id="@+id/textview1"   
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:textSize="17sp"
     />
     <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:id="@+id/textview2"   
     android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:textSize="17sp"
     />
    <ImageView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
     />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Although I appreciate your effort here, please don't spoon-feed. I would rather give the person a direction and let him/her work on it.

Comment: @Abhijit Newbie is always newbie they may learn from one or more practical things rather it is Q/A site. Some times direction may leads to wrong destination ,We have to show how the coding is, better with its explanation. Same thing i did

Answer (score 1):

Try this, its very simple and the layout will not get distorted in any resolution which using a relative layout can distort...

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: better avoid multiple layouts if possible in that way the system needs more resources to paint and repaint them! related article: http://www.curious-creature.org/docs/android-performance-case-study-1.html

Answer (score 1):

You could feasibly achieve the desired display with a single `TextView` widget.  You can use a `SpannableString` or `SpannableStringBuilder` to display text with mixed formatting and `TextView.setCompoundDrawables` or `TextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` to display an image to the right of the text.